# Enable and disable debugger in Ipython/Jupyter, skip breakpoints in disabled mode

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I found that to activate a debugger in jupyter, I just need to use `set_trace`

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

def add_to_life_universe_everything(x):
    answer = 42
    set_trace()
    answer += x

    return answer

add_to_life_universe_everything(12)
```

When I run the cell, I get an interactive debugger breakpoint inside `add_to_life_universe_everything` method. Awesome. But, sometimes, in fact most times I would like the code to run without breakpoints. I can do this by removing/commenting `set_trace()`, but I don't want to do that everytime.

I am looking for something like debugger.disable() / debugger.enable() , which will disable/enable all the breakpoints i.e `set_trace()` in jupyter.

Comment: I'm also looking for the solution for this. Globally disable all Tracer()() of IPython.core.debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%debug` magic command inside jupyter notebook and it will take you the location of error only if there is an error in your code. And you can use all the debug commands to move up the error stack trace.